# Site getting blocked on corporate networks

Tags: blocking

Our site is getting blocked in corporate networks across various companies, but not all. Would appreciate help on what could be the reasons for this and how we can resolve this?

Attached are a couple of snapshots that customers have sent us from the companies where the site is getting blocked.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2ca59a8460.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that some corporate networks have filters and/or proxy servers which are blocking the outgoing connection from their network.  Perhaps they don't want their employees doing whatever your site offers on company time.

If your site is something those people are supposed to have access to, they should go talk to their network administrator or IT support desk to see about getting an exception added to the filter so they can get through.

Answer (score 0):

Many corporate networks only allow web traffic out on port 80.  Are using some other port?

If it is based on content then you need to contact Websense and ask why your site is being blocked.